# Regex To Parse Street Names

Tags: java, regex

I have the following code that I would like to use to capture street names from an address string.

For an address of "77 ELM ST", the code below gives me "ELM" which is correct.

For an address of "115 GEORGE APPLETON FOX ST" the code gives "APPLETON".  The expected result should be " GEORGE APPLETON FOX"

For example:

```
private static String ADDRESS_PATTERN = "^\\d*\\s*(\\w+\\s*)*ST$";

public String parseStreet(String address) {
    Pattern addressPattern = Pattern.compile(ADDRESS_PATTERN);
    Matcher matcher = addressPattern.matcher(address);
    boolean found = matcher.find();
    return found ? matcher.group(1).trim() : null;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I would expect that regex to give you `FOX` instead. Are you sure it gives `APPLETON`?

Comment: Yes it is giving APPLETON

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the capturing groups around the submatch you want to capture. For example:

```
"^\\d*\\s*((?:\\w+\\s*)*)ST$"
```

Comment: Thanks!  Capturing the submatch works.  I was able to use:  ""^\\d*\\s*((\\w+\\s*)*)ST$".  Your solution also suggests using the ?:.  What purpose does that serve?

Comment: `(?:...)` is a non-capturing group. It's good practice to only capture the stuff you need.

Comment: @user106563 `?:` is used to create a non-capturing group, here we don't want to capture individual words of the street name but rather the entire street name.